# Publish and consume message on confluent control center (localhost:9021) using Node.js app

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I set up confluent platform on my local machine (mac), which is running on "localhost:9021".

Now I want to create a simple app using node.js, so that I can publish and consume message on the confluent GUI which is running on "localhost:9021".

How can I connect node.js app with this GUI , so that I can publish and consume message through that.

I know I can setup apache kafka and connect it with the node, but I want to know how I can use confluent control center (localhost:9021) GUI with node.js to publish and consume message.

[image: Confluent Control Center running on localhost:9021]

Answer (score 0):

Kafka isn't running on localhost:9021, that is *Confluent Control Center*, which has no NodeJS communication capabilities in order to get data in/out of Kafka.

If you want to communicate with **Apache** Kafka (which is part of Confluent **Platform**), then its default port is `9092`, not `9021`, and you don't require Confluent Platform for this.

After you connect to the actual broker, you can use Control Center to monitor the cluster health, read the produced messages for topics, or setup Kafka Connectors / KSQL queries.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks for the help.

Comment: If this answers your question, please use the checkmark next to the post to accept